# how to run ms sql script using java program

Tags: java, sql-server

I have Script like this :

```
USE master;  
GO  

--Delete the TestData database if it exists.  
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from sys.databases WHERE name='TestData')  
BEGIN  
    DROP DATABASE TestData;  
END  

--Create a new database called TestData.  
CREATE DATABASE TestData;
```

Using This Code :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/test.sql")); 
                String str;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(str + "\n "); 
                    } 
                in.close();  
                statement.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
```

I got Error: Incorrect syntax near GO.

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong and you shouldn't be executing a SQL script like that way. Rather wrap the entire SQL script in a `stored procedure` and call that procedure from your application code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DBAction
AS
BEGIN
--Delete the TestData database if it exists.  
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from master.sys.databases WHERE name='TestData')  
BEGIN  
    DROP DATABASE TestData;  
END     
--Create a new database called TestData.  
CREATE DATABASE TestData; 
END
```

Comment: I have try but my sql script is so big so i think that's not good way to call stored procedure. and that script is run when i remove the syntax GO.

Comment: @Yuvi, you are doing it in wrong way. That's not recommended at all. Though you can refer the system views using 3 part naming.

Answer (score 0):

GO is not a Transact-SQL statement and you are passing GO to SQL-Server to execute it. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.110).aspx

Applications based on the ODBC or OLE DB APIs receive a syntax error if they try to execute a GO command. The SQL Server utilities never send a GO command to the server.